# Bash : improve variable indirection assignment in one line

Tags: bash, shell, variables, gitlab-ci, indirection

In my Gitlab project, I set the Gitlab variables `MY_VAR_DEV` and `MY_VAR_PROD`.

Depending on the commit branch, I want a different behavior on the CI/CD pipeline (.gitlab-ci.yml file), according to the below code:

```
- if [ $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" ]; then export ENV="DEV"; fi
- if [ $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "prod" ]; then export ENV="PROD"; fi
- TMP_MY_VAR="MY_VAR_${ENV}"
- export MY_VAR=$( eval echo \$$TMP_MY_VAR )
#- ... bla bla with $MY_VAR use
```

Is there a way to merge the last 2 lines and directly affect to `MY_VAR` the value of the evaluation of the `MY_VAR_${ENV}` ? (I mean no use of `TMP_MY_VAR`)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) is a comprehensive source on the subject.

Comment: Another aside, `[ $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" ]` quotes exactly the wrong thing. Robustly correct code would look like `[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" = dev ]` -- the constant doesn't need quoting; the parameter expansion _does_ need quoting to work right with all possible values; and the only POSIX-standard string comparison operator for `test` is `=`, not `==`.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an indirect assignment, it's an indirect dereference. Assuming bash 4.x:

```
# append all-caps version of CI_COMMIT_BRANCH contents to MY_VAR_prefix
var="MY_VAR_${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH^^}"

# dereference variable created above, assign result to MY_VAR
MY_VAR=${!var}
```

...and of course, you can make the whole thing one line:

```
var="MY_VAR_${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH^^}"; MY_VAR=${!var}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's something to be said for repeating yourself *a little*.

```
- if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" = "dev" ]; then MY_VAR=$MY_VAR_DEV; fi
- if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" = "prod" ]; then MY_VAR=$MY_VAR_PROD; fi
- export MY_VAR
#- ... bla bla with $MY_VAR use
```

or

```
- case $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in dev) MY_VAR=$MY_VAR_DEV ;; prod) MY_VAR=$MY_VAR_PROD ;; esac
- export MY_VAR
```

There's no need to complicate matters with indirect parameter expansion, especially if you are using a shell that doesn't support it without extremely fragile uses of `eval`.

(Unless `MY_VAR` is used by another program *executed by* your shell, it doesn't need to be exported.)

Comment: a multiline case would be a bit more readable.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't want to bother remembering the rules for multiline values in (what I presume is) a YAML file.